# How to change values in the shared preference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I've created an application which uses a shared preference in order for the user to login. The password of the user is saved in the preference. My problem is, how can I change the password in the preference if the user wants to change his/her password?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ... // you already know how to use prefs and have one of this objects
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("password", "new value");
editor.apply();
```

Comment: It is better to use editor.apply() to do the commit asynchronously

Answer (score 8):

### Use `apply()` instead of `commit()`

It is **recommended** that you use `Editor.apply()` instead of `commit()` because `apply()` works asynchronously in the background therefore it is less likely that there will be ANR because of that(if at all).

```
getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", 0 /*FILE_MODE*/)
     .edit()
     .putString("password", "new value")
     .apply();
```

[Docs mention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) about `apply()`,

> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
>   SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the
>   requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   SharedPreferences.
>
> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time,
>   the last one to call apply wins.
>
> **Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk** and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
>   this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
>   still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
>   completed as well as the commit itself.
>
> As SharedPreferences instances are singletons within a process, it's
>   safe to replace any instance of commit() with apply() if you were
>   already ignoring the return value.
>
> You don't need to worry about Android component lifecycles and their
>   interaction with apply() writing to disk. The framework makes sure
>   in-flight disk writes from apply() complete before switching states.